# Using Terminal in Recovery Mode to Delete files or directories using -rm command (not working)

Tags: terminal, finder, filevault

**Edit: please refer instead to** [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/429398/352457) **for solution.**

I use File Vault, if that matters.

Goal: use Recovery Mode to inoculate a folder on my desktop called Applications, which I did not place there.

Recovery mode attempts to delete were fruitless "no directory found" was the common response to these various commands (note, the 2nd-to-last had a typo and was therefore re-executed below it).

[image]

Edit: Details for context:

1. The directory folder is named Applications.  I never made this directory--it just showed up on my desktop well over two years ago.
2. Trying to delete the directory from within Finder ⟩ Desktop, results in the Core Audio sound called "Boop."
3. Unable to change permissions on the directory or files.
4. Previous attempts to delete the directory from within Terminal, using various rm and rm -r commands, did not work.

Comment: Ryan - Do you still have this problem, or did one of the previous answers solve the problem?  I may have an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

From a shell (Terminal window), enter: `chflags -R nouchg`  and then drag a file into the shell to automatically populate the path (folder hierarchy).

Then enter: `rm -rf`  and drag a file in again.

Remember to add a space at the end of both commands.

`chflags` sets a POSIX permission; `-R` means apply the command recursively; `nouchg` means the file can be changed.  `rm` is simply remove; `-rf` means recursively and force.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sudo rm -rf /Users/userNAME/Desktop/folder` in a regular terminal (it may ask for password)? If that doesn’t work, you’ll have to boot into recovery mode, open terminal, and `rm -rf /Users/userName/Desktop/folder`. This even bypasses SIP. This should, if you do not enter the wrong command, delete nothing but the folder, but always keep a TM backup in case you fat-finger a * in.