# FileVault users who are unable to delete files by shell command from Terminal Recovery Mode, here's what to do

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line, recovery, filevault

This solution applies to **FileVault** users who are unable to modify permissions of pesky directories (file folders) or files themselves, in order to delete them.

Working with Terminal while in Recovery Mode is required.  However, you are still able to access the contents of this thread from within there, which Jean shows how to do, below.

All: please edit if I forgot anything.  Here are the steps

1. Open Terminal
2. Drag, from the Finder, the file(s) or directories you wish to delete.  Drop the folder into Terminal.  This will simply make the path of the file(s) or folder(s) visible.  Write this down, if necessary, as the path to the file/folder you wish to delete, must be entered entered manually (into Terminal) upon booting your computer into Recovery Mode.
3. Write down your Stack Exchange username and password
4. Boot in Recovery Mode by holding Command + R from a cold boot
5. Click on your username (Big Sur), enter your password, then click *Next* to ultimately enter into Recovery Mode. (This step might be unique to FileVault users).
6. Click Utilities (top menu), then select Terminal.
7. Enter Command + N to produce two working Terminal windows.
8. From one of the two Terminal windows, type `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/safari` [enter] (this is case-sensitive)
9. When Safari loads, enter https://apple.stackechange.com as your URL, then log-in with the username and password retained in Step-3.  A primary reason for doing this, is to copy/paste the various shell commands that follow in these steps.  The are long, and yours could be longer.
10. Locate the Disk ID for your drive labeled **APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩**.  This is attained by entering, in Terminal, `diskutil list internal` [enter]
11. Proceed to the steps defined by Jean_JD in the solution just below, with the green check.  The first command requires you to know your Disk ID you acquired through Step-10.

Note: the folder/directory (and contents with it) that I wanted gone, was a folder called *Applications* that was stuck on my Desktop.  There was no way to gain permissions to delete this folder from the Info Inspector (Command+I) or by any other means after loggin-in as myself to Big Sur.  Using conventional "rm -R" commands from within Terminal while logged-in, were unsuccessful.  The only way this problem got fixed, was to do the surgery from Terminal while in Recovery Mode.

Comment: This is just a rehash of  [Using Terminal in Recovery Mode to Delete files or directories using -rm command (not working)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429384/using-terminal-in-recovery-mode-to-delete-files-or-directories-using-rm-command) Also, please provide terminal data as text not images & don't use remote images at all, upload to here. A more senior member can inline them if the system won't allow you.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below, so people can find it in the place they expect it to be.

Comment: Unfortunately this still is an answer posted as an question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.

Can you excute the command :

```
diskutil ap unlockvolume disk3s5
```

Then enter your password and give the result of (replace Your_name by your real name):

```
ls -l /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Your_name/Desktop/Applications
```

I think you will find your application to suppress and the command :

```
rm -r /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Your_name/Desktop/Applications
```

**Edit 1** :

I add the command who has unlock the Applications directory under the User Desktop from recovery mode.

The above command has return this error :

*rm: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/<my_username>/Desktop/Applications/Karabiner-Elements.app/Contents: Operation not permitted override rwxr-xr-x root/wheel **schg** for /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/<my_username/Desktop/Applications/Karabiner-Elements.app?*

So the command bellow has suppress this :

```
chflags -R noschg /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/<my_username>/Desktop/Applications
```

Edit 2:

@Ryan : Your system container structure is bad (you have two volumes "Macintosh HD - Data").

I think this one is too much :

1:   APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩  678.6 MB   disk3s1

To verify, can you give the results of :

```
diskutil ap listgroups
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a longish comment? If it should be an answer, can you please include the steps which apparently worked for the OP and which are listed in the question now?

Comment: @nohillside I will try to draft a succinct answer later today. Jean ultimately found the solution after spending hours of their time helping to fix this issue.  I can see how my green-check could confuse some, as the term "Applications" was unique to my own case, in which *Applications* was the actual folder-name stuck on my desktop.  I can probably clean this up a little.

Comment: @Ryan Hare you ready to repair your System Container?